# Filter test projects executed by the TestDriven.NET runner

Tags: testdriven.net

Is it possible to filter which test projects are executed when using the TestDriven.NET runner in the solution explorer? I want to run the unit tests without running the integration tests, as the latter ones take longer to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio, go to Tools/Options/TestDriven.Net where you can specify which categories to include and exclude.  You can separate categories with ';'.  You can mark a test with a category by applying the category attribute:

```
[Test]
[Category("Integration")]
public void Test_IntegrationIsWorking()
{
   // do some testing
}
```

You can also apply a category to a whole test fixture:

```
[TestFixture]
[Category("Integration")]
public class IntegrationTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test_IntegrationIsWorking()
    {
        // do some testing
    }
}
```